# Is it possible to have multiple RSA private keys?

Tags: rsa

I just did some math:

1. Pick $p$ and $q$ distinct primes;
2. Calculate $N=p\cdot q$;
3. Calculate Euler`s totient => $\phi=(p-1)\cdot(q-1)$;
4. Pick an $e$ (public key), coprime with $\phi$;
5. Calculate $d$ (private key) which is equal to $e^{-1} \bmod \phi$.

And figured out that $d$ (private key) can be multi-valued:

$$d = (\phi * k + 1) / e$$

This $k$ lets calculate a lot of different $d$`s. And are all of them correct private keys?

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I think you're getting yourself confused about modulo math. `E^(-1) (mod φ)` yields a unique value. Adding `(kφ + E^-1) (mod φ)` does produce the same result, but that's not the equation you're required to compute.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on if the $/e$ in the latter equation is supposed to be regular division, or multiplication by the inverse $e^{-1}$. If division, where did the idea come from? If multiplication with the inverse, there should (trivially) be any number of matching $d = \phi*k*e^{-1} + e^{-1}$ since they are all congruent $mod \space \phi$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are wrong in assuming that any $(\phi * k + 1) / e$ gives modular inverse of $e$ modulo $\phi$; actually if $e$ and $\phi$ are coprime the modular inverse $d \in [0..\phi-1]$ such that $de = 1 (\mod \phi)$ is unique, and only a single $k \in [0..e-1]$ gives the modular inverse.

As an example consider $(p,q) = (5,11)$, $\phi= 4\cdot 10 = 40$. Let us choose $e=3$, coprime with $\phi$: $gcd(3, 40) = 1$; then $d=e^{-1}(\mod 40) = 27$.

Using your expression:

- $(k = 0) : 0$ (wrong)
- $(k = 1) : (40 + 1) / 3 = 13$ (wrong)
- $(k = 2) : (40\cdot 2 + 1) / 3 = 27$ (got it, $27 * 3 \mod 40 = 1$)

But the choice of decrypting exponent is indeed not unique. To obtain the minimal decrypting exponent one should use $d^\prime=e^{-1}(\mod lcm((p-1),(q-1)))$ instead of $d=e^{-1}(\mod (p-1)(q-1))$. For the above example, $lcm(4,10) = 20$ and $d^\prime=7$, which is less than $d=27$ and so a better (faster) decrypting exponent.

As a sanity check, let us encrypt/decrypt number $8$:

- encryption:  $8^3 \mod 55 = 17$
- decryption using $d=27$:  $17^{27} \mod 55 = 8$
- decryption using $d^{\prime}=7$:   $17^{7} \mod 55 = 8$

Any $d=7+k\cdot 20$ where $k = 0, 1, 2, ..$ is a valid decryption exponent for the above example.

Comment: @kludg: the $de= 1\mod\phi$ in your answer parses literally as $de=(1\bmod\phi)$, that is $de=1$, which (assuming $e>1$) has no integer solution. You perhaps mean $de\equiv1\pmod\phi$, but contrary to the answer's statement this allows multiple $d$ (if $d$ is valid, then $d+\phi$ is). On the other hand, $d=e^{-1}\bmod\phi$, to be parsed as $d=(e^{-1}\bmod\phi)$, does uniquely define $d$. This is not the only working $d$ for RSA though; any $d$ such that $de\equiv1\pmod{\operatorname{LCM}(p-1,q-1)}$ will do.

Comment: @fgrieu thank you, you are right, the choice of decrypting exponent $d$ is not unique; the interesting choice though is minimal possible $d$ , since the use of $d=e^{-1}\mod lcm(p-1,q-1)$ instead of  $d=e^{-1} \mod \phi(p-1,q-1)$. $d+\phi$ is valid but not interesting.