# Decrypt Ciphertext Using different private key, given knowledge of original private key

Tags: rsa

A message, `m` is encrypted using a private key `d`.

```
p = prime()
q = prime()
e = 65537
c = pow(m, e, n)
PHI = (p-1)*(q-1)
d = mod_inverse(e, PHI)
```

Assume all these values are known to the attacker, except for the message (`m`) and ciphertext (`c`).

Is it possible to find an **alternate** value for d such that:

```
c ^ d_alternative % n == m (the ciphertext decrypts correctly to the message)
```

And

```
d_alternative % PHI != d (the new d modulus PHI does not equal the old d)
```

This second part is the catch: `d` and `d_alternative` cannot be modularly congruent.

**Is this possible, and if so, how?**

Comment: In addition p and q must be distinct, and p-1,q-1 both coprime to e for this to work at all. `d_alternative = d + k*lambda where lambda = lcm(p-1,q-1) aka Carmichael's totient and k is any integer not divisible by gcd(p-1,q-1)` . This is because a valid `d` could have been computed in the first place as `mod_inverse(e,lambda)` as covered by dozens of existing Qs and wikipedia.

Comment: Yes, that's possible for any definition of RSA that allows $d=e^{-1}\bmod\varphi(n)$.  See [answers there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/87583/more-than-one-private-key-for-rsa) and [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39486/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-rsa-private-keys). One simple option is to use $$d'=\begin{cases}d-\varphi(n)/2&\text{if }2d>\varphi(n)\\d+\varphi(n)/2&\text {otherwise}\end{cases}$$